# Antiforgery token issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have my ASP.NET MVC5 application which is hosted on IIS and recently I have changed its authentication to "Anonymous" from "Windows" since we wanted to have AAD token for some API call.

We are seeing issues. Whenever the application is opened from Internet Explorer there are exceptions:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

We added the `Authorize` attribute in the action methods and added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the `.cshtml` file.

The same application runs fine in Microsoft Edge and in Chrome.

The application should work in IE as well as its working on Edge and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Since it works fine in Chrome, FireFox and Edge, this issue isn't be caused by code. It must be related to some settings in IE.

The way the anti forgery helper 
`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`
works is by injecting a hidden form field named `__RequestVerificationToken` into the page AND it also sets a cookie into the browser. When the form is posted back the two are compared and if they don't match or the cookie is missing then the error is thrown.

Please check the Cookie Settings of Opera, make sure Opera accept the cookie that  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` sets.

About how to enable Cookie in IE: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-cookies/internet-explorer

May be this will help you.